# How to generate the PEM serialization for the public RSA/DSA key

Tags: python, openssl, pycrypto, pyopenssl

Using PyCrypto I was able to generate the public and private PEM serialization for a RSA key, but in PyCrypto the DSA class has no exportKey() method.

Trying PyOpenSSL I was able to generate the private PEM serialization for RSA and DSA keys, bu there is no crypto.dump_publickey method in PyOpenSSL.

I am looking for suggestion of how to generate the PEM serialization for RSA and DSA keys.

Many thanks!

PS: meanwhile I have changed the PyOpenSSL code to also export an dump_privatekey method for crypto API. PyOpenSSL bug and patch can be found at: https://bugs.launchpad.net/pyopenssl/+bug/780089

---

I was already using Twisted.conch so I solved this problem by manually generating a DSA/RSA key using PyCrypto and then initializing a twisted.conch.ssh.key.Key using this key. The Key class from Conch provides a toString method for string serialization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not clear what you are doing this for, but if all you want is an openssl-compatible DSA private key, you should just follow the openssl [dsa(1) manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dsa):

> The DER option with a private key uses
>   an ASN1 DER encoded form of an ASN .1
>   SEQUENCE consisting of the values of
>   version (currently zero), p, q, g, the
>   public and private key components
>   respectively as ASN .1 INTEGERs.

This is an example how to export/import DSA private keys in openssl format:

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import DSA
from Crypto.Util import asn1

key = DSA.generate(1024)

# export

seq = asn1.DerSequence()
seq[:] = [ 0, key.p, key.q, key.g, key.y, key.x ]

exported_key = "-----BEGIN DSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n%s-----END DSA PRIVATE KEY-----" % seq.encode().encode("base64")

print exported_key

# import

seq2 = asn1.DerSequence()
data = "\n".join(exported_key.strip().split("\n")[1:-1]).decode("base64")
seq2.decode(data)
p, q, g, y, x = seq2[1:]

key2 = DSA.construct((y, g, p, q, x))

assert key == key2
```

Comment: Thank for your valuable example. I just want to generate the key pairs from Python so that they can be used with OpenSSH. I was looking after the _public key part_. For the public key, I think that I need the **SubjectPublicKeyInfo** as this is what I read from the man page `When used with a public key it uses a SubjectPublicKeyInfo structure: it is an error if the key is not DSA.` Thanks again!

Comment: I found the public key format in the Twisted code : http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/tags/releases/twisted-11.0.0/twisted/conch/ssh/keys.py#L93

Comment: In this case may be you should check with [paramiko](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/) sources.

Comment: For now Twisted.conch.ssh.key solved my problem. Your answer did not directly solved my problem, but it gave me a good start and motivation to look around for documentation :)

Comment: [keyczar](http://keyczar.org) has some more detailed conversion routines in [keyczar.util](http://www.keyczar.org/pydocs/keyczar.util-module.html)

Comment: For RSA use seq[:] = [ 0, key.n, key.e ]